# How to write a character who has the ability to manipulate diamagnetism?

Tags: fantasy, science-fiction

I am trying to adapt a character who has Diamagnetic Manipulation abilities (https://powerlisting.fandom.com/wiki/Diamagnetism_Manipulation) into my own universe. Although I know superpowers do not exist in the real world, I still feel like there are realistic ways to write them, and I would like to make the sci-fi element of this character lean more towards the science part as much as possible. However, since I am no scientist, I struggle to read a lot of the jargon used in scientific explanations. Despite reading the definitions of Magnetism, Diamagnetism, Magnetic Field, Lines of Force, etc. too many times to count, I can’t seem to wrap my head around it.

Basically, what I need to know is, if something is Diamagnetic, does that mean it is repelled by magnets or that it repels magnets away from it? Or is it both? And would this person be able to wear clothes, or would their body repel the clothing away from touching their body? This character is also described as having a belt that can be used to regulate the strength of his magnetic “aura” so as to prevent everything around him from being pushed away. In Sci-Fi logic, how could the belt do this? And what material would it have to be made out of for him to even be able to wear it in the first place? I’ve been told it can’t be anything magnetic because it would heat up from the energy of being attracted to his body, but if I make it a non-magnetic material, it’ll be diamagnetic and be repelled away from his body. So what do I do?

Just for clarification: I am trying to rewrite a pretty 2-dimensional character into something more fleshed out and somewhat more “plausible” despite it still being in the sci-fi territory. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: Voting to close because this is off-topic here

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! Not only is this question off-topic - it's a science question, not a writing question - it's also [reposted verbatim from Worldbuilding.SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/217640/32016), and therefore I have closed it. Please don't post the same question on multiple Stack Exchange sites, especially when it's off-topic on those sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, to answer your questions in order, since I've studied Physics:

1. Diamagnetism is the way an object is repelled by a magnetic field. It is weakly present in all materials, but it is practically nonexistent in nearly all of them. It's the exact inverse of the force that allows you to connect paper clips to a magnet in a chain. (Newton's third law of motion states that it also repels magnets, but explicitly because of that.
2. Yes, they would be able to wear clothes just like any of us.
3. This is an interesting question, since it is hard to figure out. The only thing I can think of is that the power wouldn't work if the belt is off.
4. Anything non-magnetic (copper, plastic, etc.) would theoretically work, and any magnetic material would just squish him/her a bit extra. So yeah, pretty much anything.

(Just as a note, even I had to look up what Diamagnetism is, so you may be able to stretch the definition of it. In this direct form, it seems pretty useless!)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for taking time to answer. So plastic, which I’ve been told is diamagnetic, wouldn’t be repelled by his body? The belt is supposed to make it so not everything in the room goes flying away from him

Comment: @AnthonyFallone Yes. Diamagnetic objects repel magnets, and are repelled by magnets. Let's be honest, that's pretty useless. You could easily change it (because very few people reading a Superhero sci-fi would really care about Quantum Physics stuff) so that he repels all _nonmagnetic_ materials, which may be the effect you are going for.

Comment: Yes. I was wanting him to be able to repel diamagnetic materials. So considering that, would have to use some paramagnetic material for the belt to be able to make contact with his body? Or would that heat up too much from the energy?

Comment: @AnthonyFallone Ok, the answers would be nearly the same. However, (1) you could invent a material like Unobtainium or Adamantium for the belt to be made of (with its own properties, not indestructibility. Those were just the first one's I thought of). Which would also help a ton with how it controls his powers.